Why running zsh with arch -x86_64 runs the terminal in i386 mode?
The combination of commands:
arch -x86_64 zsh
arch

echoes

i386

But, x86_64 means a 64-bit instruction set, while i386 is a 32-bit instruction set. So the zsh is actually run in 32-bits mode even though I wanted it run in 64-bits. Can this be remedied somehow, and firstly, why does it happen?

What is your macOS Version? macOS does not run any 32-bit programs since Cataline (10.15), but the arch command reports "i386" for some historical reasons, as said in the suggested duplicate target, and also explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12763379/1187415
